# retrieve only custom folders from IMAP server

Tags: gmail, imap

I would like to know if there's a way to query an IMAP server in order to retrieve only custom folders and not the system ones too. For example, for a Gmail account, if I created two labels `subfolder1` and `subfolder2`, I would like to receive, after the query, only that two labels and not the folders `[Gmail]/Draft`, `[Gmail]/Trashcan`, `[Gmail]/Sent`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

with standard IMAP protocol (as per rfc3501) it is not possible. May be an extension might provide it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Ansh. I tried with XLIST command too, that should give extended flags information too but it returns useful information only with Gmail (for what I tested), while for Yahoo for example it returns the same flags for all folders (regardless if they are system ones or user ones). Maybe can I determine the folder type by its name?

Comment: Why can you not just get the list and filter out anything that starts with [Gmail] (or [Googlemail])?

Comment: Because I have to get the list of user folders for any provider, and not a specific one.

Comment: IMAP doesn't include, in general, a concept of 'custom folders' and 'system folders'.  The only guaranteed system folder is INBOX.  Everything else is merely convention.  The sent folder is whatever you call it.  Some will support LIST extension for Special-Use-Folders (XLIST is deprecated), like gmail.   On a non-webmail service (like, a standard install of courier or dovecot or whatever), there is no difference between a folder named Sent and a folder named Family&Friends.  It would be completely heuristic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Max, I will take it in consideration.